# Java randomly select list with maintain order

Tags: java, list, algorithm

I want to make a random list from the list,
but the conditions are a bit tricky, so I'm thinking about how to implement it.

list   [A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3]

example

result1 [A1,B1,A2,C1,A3,B2,C2,C3,B3]
result2 [C1,B1,B2,A1,A2,B3,C2,A3,C3]

I want to put it with maintain order into a new list.

Is there an algorithmically good way?

Comment: Do you mean the letters undergo a random permutation but the numbers grouped by the letter remain in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you conceptually arrange your data as a `HashMap<Integer, Queue<T>>`, structured as

```
0: A1,A2,A3
1: B1,B2,B3
2: C1,C2,C3
```

Then once you've chosen your random number you can just do `map.get(number).dequeue()` to get your value

Edit: See discussion with Neil in the comments to this answer, it perhaps isn't the best answer for the question as it is phrased now. In particular, if it is used, the random number must be chosen very carefully for a random distribution of values

Comment: To make it truly random, you need to weight the letters by how many numbers are _remaining_, see popular [Monty Hall problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem).

Comment: @Neil I don't follow how the Monty Hall problem is related, could you elaborate?

Comment: The probabilities must be updated as new information becomes available. Say in the case where you had 2 letters, `{ A1..100, B1 }`, if you took a coin toss to see which of `A, B` should be chosen, then you would have `B1` appearing near the front with high probability. Must draw from 101 objects, 100 of them are `A`.

Comment: Ahhhh of course, you're right, that's a very good point. I wrote this originally when the question said "make a random number 0,1,2 , if 0 select A If 1 select B If 2 select C" which I interpreted as part of the requirements, but upon the edit I see it was not.

Comment: It _is_ a good solution, orthogonal to the other shuffle solution. I would add that, instead of a letter, that you are picking a list item out of a bag without replacement. All the A items will be indistinguishable, and so forth. The probabilities change each time, until there is one item and one spot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by randomly arranging them using `Collections.shuffle()` and then correcting them using a map.

```
static List<String> shuffleTricky(List<String> list) {
    List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(list);
    Collections.shuffle(copy);
    Map<String, Deque<String>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0, 1),
            Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new)));
    return copy.stream()
        .map(s -> map.get(s.substring(0, 1)).pop())
        .toList();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3");
    List<String> result = shuffleTricky(list);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

output:

```
[C1, A1, B1, C2, B2, B3, A2, C3, A3]
```

Elements with the same first letter will remain in order after shuffling.